# Rotate 2d-Vector around point

Tags: vector-spaces

i know its a pretty basic question. But can someone show me how to rotate the red dot around the center of the semicircle. At first the dotted line is my initial point i want to rotate the red dot to the left/right side of the semicircle. So as input for the needed function i have just degrees and i need to calculate the red dot's position as a 2d vector.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aE16w.jpg)

Comment: It completely depends on the mechanics of how you produce the dot in the first place and on what is an acceptable rotation. If you're doing a freehand drawing and any non-zero rotation is acceptable, just draw another dot somewhere else on the semicircle, and voilá, you have rotated the dot. If you want a better answer I think it would be wise for you to provide more details about what you're working with.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to rotate it by an angle ‘m’

And it’s current position is (x,y) = (0,-5.4)
And let’s take its new position as (x’,y’)
Take 
x‘^2+y‘^2 = (5.4)^2

Also 
(x.x’)+(y.y’)=5.4^2 cos(m)

Two equations and two variables. Solvable!

(Assuming that you want the position of the new dot)
 Basically if ā and ē are two pos vectors, |ā|=|ē|=5.4
If ā= xî+yj, ē=x’î+y’j

ā.ē=|ā||ē|cos(m)

ā.ē=(xx’)+(yy’)